# Iterating through a matching set of before and after raster images in Python

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have downloaded a matching set of before and after insect invasion raster images from Google Earth Engine. I now want to loop through these images selecting the matching before and after invasion image and then calculating the difference between these sets of images.

How can I write a loop through this list selecting an after and before image to calculate the difference? The list has more than 300 sets of before and after rasters. I have tried writing a for loop function using rasterio but was stuck.

The code that I am working on is;

````
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import folium 
import rasterio
from rasterio import plot
from rasterio.plot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import os
data_pkg_path = 'DATA_ANALYSIS'
filename = 'Before_After_Image_Composites'
composites = os.listdir(filename) 
print(composites)```

Sample of the list I get when I print the composites;

['point_306_after_2020-07-07.tif', 'point_306_before_2020-07-07.tif', 'point_307_after_2020-07-12.tif', 'point_307_before_2020-07-12.tif', 'point_308_after_2020-07-01.tif', 'point_308_before_2020-07-01.tif']
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your comparison is for the following pairs:

```
'point_306_after_2020-07-07.tif', 'point_306_before_2020-07-07.tif', 
'point_307_after_2020-07-12.tif', 'point_307_before_2020-07-12.tif', 
'point_308_after_2020-07-01.tif', 'point_308_before_2020-07-01.tif'
```

All you need to do is find the files with the relevant wildcard (say the after files), find the equivalent "before" file, read both and subtract:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from osgeo import gdal
differences = {}
for after_file in Path("DATA_ANALYSIS").glob("point_*_after_*.tif"):
    s2 = after_file.as_posix()
    s1 = after.replace("_after_", "_before_")
    if not (Path("DATA_ANALYSIS")/s1).exists():
       print(f"Cannot find before file for {after_file}")
    output = after_file.name.replace("_after_", "_difference_")
    differences[output] = (gdal.Open(s2).ReadAsArray() -
                           gdal.Open(s1).ReadAsArray()
                          )
```